# Texstudio and "Package Babel Error"

Tags: packages, texstudio, babel, texmf

I have updated Texstudio on my Mac to Version 4.2.1.

Running the following tex-file brings me two errors.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
    
    A B C

\end{document}
```

Errors:

```
 Zeile 4281: Package babel Error: Unknown option 'ngerman'. Either you misspelled it(babel) or the language definition file ngerman.ldf was not found. \ProcessOptions*
Zeile 9: File `carlito.sty' not found.
```

When I delete/comment both rows (`\usepackage{carlito}` and `\usepackage{babel}`) in the tex-file, it works. Downgrading to Version 4.0.4 does not change anything.

Furthermore, Texstudio does not find my locally installed classes and style-files in `library/texmf/tex/latex`.

Can anyone tell me, what went wrong with the update?

Comment: texstudio isn't really involvd here, it's just the editor you used to edit the source, the errors come from  tex (mactex installation perhaps?)

Comment: No, Texstudio seems to be the problem. The tex-file works fine in Texmaker and TexShop

Comment: The error messages you show certainly come from tex not from the editor. Perhaps you have two tex systems installed and you have different path settings in the editors picking up different tex systems.  If you added the log file from a working run in texmaker and the failing run in texstudio then someone could compare and debug.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you!
Texmaker and TexShop referred to the right tex installation. Texstudio referred to TinyTex. I deleted the TinyTex folder and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages you show come from tex not from the editor. Perhaps you have two tex systems installed and you have different path settings in the editors picking up different tex systems.

Comparison ofthe log file from a working run in texmaker and the failing run in texstudio woul dshow which systems are being used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) I found the answer.

Checking the log protocol I found out that Texstudio was linked to the wrong Tex installation. It was linked to "TinyTex" instead of MacTex.

After deleting TinyTex and restarting Texstudio, it works again.